# How can I enable search on parts of a word and autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: views, 8, search

I'm using Search API in Drupal 8.

I tried with Search API pages and even views, but I didn't find `%like%` function query

Can I do %like% in Search API or Views?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click in "Edit" this Database server, and navigate to the end of that page:

[image]